# RadGrid AJAX postback removes IE conditional comment

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik, stylesheet, radgrid, conditional-comments

I have a Telerik RadGrid on my page.  I also have an IE7 specific stylesheet on my page wrapped in IE7 conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

When I click a button in my RadGrid, for example, to sort a column, the conditional comments are removed from around the LINK tag and the stylesheet gets applied to the page causing layout issues.

Any ideas why clicking a button in my RadGrid would cause the IE7 conditional comments to be removed?

I'm running Telerik.Web.UI.dll version 2010.1.519.35.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, the solution for my issue was the last bullet on this page, http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-conditional-comments.html:

> move the conditional comments out of the head tag. This way they will
>   not be updated by the RadAjaxManager and still applied depending on
>   the browser used. It is even valid xhtml1.1 as the html comments are
>   skipped by the html validator i.e